# Upload file from Angular to Laravel. Not working

Tags: angular, laravel, file-upload

I am trying to upload image from angular(frontend) to laravel(backend).

### **ANGULAR Project**

**product.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="mediaFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit();">
<input  type="file" name="thumb_nail" (change)="onFileChange($event,'thumbnail')" />
<button type="submit" >UPLOAD</button>
</form>
```

**product.component.ts**

```
 thumbFile: File;
onFileChange(event, imgType) {
 this.thumbFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
}
onSubmit(){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('thumbimage', this.thumbFile);
   this.uploadService.upload(formData).subscribe(
      data => {
        return data;
    });
}
```

**upload.service.ts**

```
public upload(data) {
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.SERVER_URL}/user/uploadImage`,data,  {
      headers: headers
    })
    .pipe(map((res) => {
            return res;
        }));
}
```

### Laravel Project

**api.php**

```
Route::post('user/uploadImage', "User\UserController@uploadImage");
```

**UserController.php**

```
public static function uploadImage(Request $request){
        //return $request->file(); // null
    //return $request; //null
        
}
```

**In laravel request is getting as null**.
What is wrong with this code?
I think someone can help me..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051184/angular-file-upload-to-laravel

Comment: https://therichpost.com/angular-10-laravel-8-image-upload-tutorial/